# Problema ao comparar horas

Tags: php, mysql

Na comparação de horários tenho na base de dados registado o horário de abertura e fechamento de uma estabelecimento. Estou a ter um problema na hora de comparar o horário para ver se o estabelecimento esta aberto ou fechado, está-me sempre a aparecer como aberto quando já passou a hora.

```
<?php
$horario = strtotime(date('H:i'));
$result_horario_estado=mysql_query("select * from horarios where id_mae='".$row->id."'");
$row_horario_estado=mysql_fetch_array($result_horario_estado);

$abertura   = strtotime($row_horario_estado['horario_abertura']);
$fechamento = strtotime($row_horario_estado['horario_fechamento']);

if($horario >= $abertura || $horario <= $fechamento) {
?>
    <div style="margin:-3px 0px 5px 0px; width:257px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#0C3; font-size:13px;">Aberto</div>
<?php
} else {
?>
    <div style="margin:-3px 0px 5px 0px; width:257px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#F00; font-size:13px;">Fechado Agora</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara incluir isso: date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); Dependendo da sua localização... tenta dar um `echo` na sua hora atual se está batendo direitinho.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente prefiro trabalhar com `gmt` (`gmdate(...)`) e converter as horas conforme "a região" ou preferencia do usuário. Se você usar `date()` poderá ter muitos problema com fuso horários e servidores "mal configurados". Eu tenho um serviço VPS e houve alguns problema no upgrade, simplesmente tive problema com várias coisas, inclusive o horário. Me corrijam eu tiver falado algo errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cara, analisa seu código.
Você tem abertura as 14 e fecha as 2.
Você tem que considerar isso. 14 é maior que 2.

```
<?php
$horario = strtotime('1:00');
$abertura = strtotime('22:00');
$fechamento = strtotime('7:00');

if ((
        $abertura < $fechamento && $horario >= $abertura && $horario <= $fechamento
        ) || (
        $abertura > $fechamento && ($horario >= $abertura || $horario <= $fechamento)
        )) {
    echo 'aberto';
} else {
    echo 'fechado';
}
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho valeu pela ajuda de todos

Comment: É verdade, eu não havia prestado atenção nesses dados.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa que as duas condições sejam atendidas:

```
if($horario >= $abertura && $horario <= $fechamento){
            //  VEJA --- ^^
```

O `&&` no lugar do `||` garante isso. No seu código, basta uma das condições para que entre no `if`, causando a exibição de mais eventos do que você gostaria.

Comment: Já tinha testado dessa forma mas agora assim fica-me sempre como fechado

Comment: Qual é o formato das datas no seu banco?

Comment: Formato está como Varchar(255)

Comment: estou a fazer por horário neste formato H:i

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem com a estrutura da base de dados dos horaios

Comment: É provável que o servidor trabalhe em UTC, mas as suas horas estão em outro fuso.

Comment: Use `echo date_default_timezone_get();` para ver o fuso horário do servidor.

Comment: Fuso Horario Europe/Lisbon

Comment: Me enganei, como tudo usa `strtotime`, fica tudo no mesmo fuso horário. Devia funcionar, veja só: http://ideone.com/y71gaf (altere os horários de inicio/fim para testar)

Comment: Realmente ai no exemplo funciona direitinho não sei por que será eu também achei que estava tudo bem até que decidi por aqui para ver se encontramos o gato

Comment: Mas aqui estive a ver e não encontro nenhum erro continua a ficar sempre como fechado