# Comparação e calculo de hora e data

Tags: php, mysql

Bom eu recupero a data e hora de um registro assim:

```
$sql = $conexao->query(select data, hora from pedido);
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

$resultado->data;
$resultado->hora;
```

Preciso adicionar 5 horas e verificar se a data é maior que a cada e hora atual.

Como posso fazer esse calculo é verificação?

Queria saver algo assim

```
if ((data e hora da tabela com + 5 horas) => (data e hora atual)) {
 echo "o pedido já foi finalizado a mais de 5 horas";
}
```

Comment: Bom com isso eu consigo adicionar horas, porém não sei como comprar.

Comment: É só comparar o retorno do `strtotime`.

Answer (score 0):

No caso de comparação podes usar algo assim:

```
<?php
$horario = strtotime('1:00');
$abertura = strtotime('22:00');
$fechamento = strtotime('7:00');

if ((
        $abertura < $fechamento && $horario >= $abertura && $horario <= $fechamento
        ) || (
        $abertura > $fechamento && ($horario >= $abertura || $horario <= $fechamento)
        )) {
    echo 'aberto';
} else {
    echo 'fechado';
}
```

[Fonte no próprio SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50845/problema-ao-comparar-horas)

Caso queira validar data e hora pode usar esta resposta tambem do SOPT: [Validar data e hora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33469/como-comparar-datas-em-php)

Comment: Tenho que usar a data também, se eu usar só a hora pode dar errados no outro dia.

Comment: @HugoBorges editei a resposta com mais uma referencia.